# Question about drawing the graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I searched about draw graph of $[\sin x]$ but I don't know how to draw it like this: 
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1U3x.png)

I have matlab and gegebra but I don't know how to do it (about points like $\pi / 2$. Is it possible to help me?
I'm sorry for ask this question in this place but I didn't found any better place.

Update:
It's gegebra screenshot:
[gegebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzNc7.png) 
Thanks.

Comment: To clarify: do you really want $[\sin x]$, i.e., the floor function applied to $\sin x$? Also, are you interested in drawing by hand, or only with software?

Comment: I want the floor function applied to sinx with points like $\pi/2$ with value for check limits and etc. I can draw it but It's not main function. my main function for check limit is $[\sin x][x]$ and I need app for draw it exactly with points.

Comment: You could always add those points (such as $(\pi/2,1)$) separately.

Comment: Yes. we can do this but sometimes I can't draw a graph so I want to check this points with app but that app doesn't show me that points and I can't test all points to find them. maybe this point like $\sqrt3 + 1$!

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of measuring angles: degrees and radians

in degrees, the wave repeats every 360 degrees, but in radians it repeats every 2 pi, this piece of software is using radians as is fairly standard for higher levels of mathematics (note, wolfram alpha also uses radians)

Comment: Thanks for answer. for example my question mean about the point $\pi/2$. the value of that different and when I draw it with geogebra, that only shows a line from 0 to $\pi$ and don't show the value of function in $\pi/2$. I hope that you understand because my English is not good.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of geogebra?

Comment: I add image to my main question.

Comment: @Ali that is utterly bizzare and i have no explanation for that

Comment: However thanks for that.